# Python: Replace 2D numpy array filled with indices by values from a 1D array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a n x m numpy python array. Values of this array range between 0 and 10 what coincides with the indices of a 1D numpy array (length of 1D array = 11, so 0-10) . This 1D array stores abritrary values. I want now to replace the indices values of my 2D array with the corresponding values from the 1D array.

How can I do this ?

Cheers
Norksen

Comment: Welcome to SO. This isn't a discussion forum or tutorial. Please take the [tour] and take the time to read [ask] and the other links found on that page.. - iterate over the 2-d array and replace each item's value with the value from the other? Or use the 2-d array as an index to the 1-d array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's straightforward with numpy: `result = values_1d[arr_idxs_2d]`

See:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> imin, imax = 0, 9

>>> values_1d = np.random.randn(imax+1)
>>> values_1d
array([-0.80355548,  1.00645905, -1.17436992, -1.52008027,  0.73544379,
       -0.72175806, -0.69933584, -0.50195895, -0.04588092,  0.86542796])

>>> arr_idxs_2d = np.random.randint(imin, imax, (4, 5))                                              

>>> arr_idxs_2d
array([[6, 7, 4, 3, 1],
       [8, 8, 3, 7, 7],
       [1, 1, 5, 3, 2],
       [6, 2, 3, 6, 8]])

>>> values_1d[arr_idxs_2d]
array([[-0.69933584, -0.50195895,  0.73544379, -1.52008027,  1.00645905],
       [-0.04588092, -0.04588092, -1.52008027, -0.50195895, -0.50195895],
       [ 1.00645905,  1.00645905, -0.72175806, -1.52008027, -1.17436992],
       [-0.69933584, -1.17436992, -1.52008027, -0.69933584, -0.04588092]])
```

Comment: Hi, that completely solves my problem! Thank you for that piece.